# How to change the width of a column individually in tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, matrices

I want to individually change the width of the different columns in the following matrix:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\matrix[column sep=4ex,fill=none] {
  \draw(0,0)--(1,1); & \draw(0,0)--(1,1); & \draw(0,1)--(1,0); & \draw(0,0)--(1,1); \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Basically what I want is something equivalent to the `@{}` operator used in arrays. I tried many options: `@{}`, `minimum width`, `minimum size`, `inner sep`, and other but none worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what you need is to add a `[]` after the `&`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[column sep=4ex,fill=none] {
          \draw(0,0)--(1,1); &[4ex] \draw(0,0)--(1,1); &[-4ex] \draw(0,1)--(1,0); &[0ex] \draw(0,0)--(1,1); \\
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works in a slight different way with respect to the `@{}` operator since the length specified inside the braces does not replace but is added to the width you specified with `column sep`. So if `column sep=4ex`, then after `&[4ex]` it will be `8ex`. `&[0ex]` will leave the width unchanged. This is documented in the manual, section 17.3.2

[image]